# How can I change the language for automatic spelling correction?

Tags: macos, language, input-source, spellcheck, spelling

I set my input source to be **US English**. And the flag showing on the taskbar is also an American flag.

But whenever I type something in `Mail.app` or `Notes.app` the spell check still corrects my spelling to **British English**:

- e.g. it highlights my "**organize**" and suggest s"**organise**".

Please, how to make my Mac (OS X 10.8) an American?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

For OS X 10.8:

**System Preferences > Languages & Text > Text > Spelling**

[image: image of control]

Or for OS X 10.9 and later:

**System Preferences > Keyboard > Text > Spelling**

Answer (score 77):

To add to what gentmatt said, in the case you need to keep "Automatic by Language" because you happen to write in different languages, click on "Set Up…" in the list shown for the Spelling option.

[image: screenshot]

On the dialog box that appears, you can change the order for the languages. In my case, this is the order I chose.

[image: screenshot]

Now, I can write *organize*, and the word is not corrected, nor do I get a suggestion for writing *organise*. (It happens that *organise* is shown as incorrect.)

Comment: and for snow lep?

Comment: In Mavericks, you can get there via System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Text -> Spelling (or Language & Region -> Keyboard Preferences -> Text -> Spelling).

Comment: Thank you, this one is the answer I was looking for as a non-native English speaker/user.

Comment: Wow! The "Set up..." for this is well hidden!

Answer (score 12):

In Mavericks (10.9):

System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Text -> Spelling

or

System Preferences -> Language & Region -> Keyboard Preferences -> Text -> Spelling

Comment: This should be a comment or an edit adding to a previous answer as it is the same just via a different menu route

Comment: Actually, it was helpful to me having this as a separate answer as the previous answer references the non-existent (in Mavericks) UX path "System Preferences → Languages & Text → Text → Spelling" path.

Answer (score 4):

Autocorrect with multiples languages (automatic by language) in Mavericks is broken. It does not underline all the bad written words. I have to select only 1 language to get it properly working.

Comment: Evidence? I'm not finding this to be the case.

Answer (score 3):

Building on the other answers, in Ventura this is now located in

> System Settings > Keyboard > Input Methods : Edit... > Automatic by Language > Set Up...

This can also be changed using the command line with :

```sh
defaults write NSGlobalDomain NSPreferredSpellServers '((en,Apple),("en_GB",Apple),(fr, Apple),(es, Apple))'
```

where the part between `'` quotes is a list of the languages you want to spell check, in order.

You can use

```sh
defaults read NSGlobalDomain NSPreferredSpellServers
```

to show the current list of languages before changing it.

---

[image: System Settings]

[image: System Settings > Keyboard]

[image: System Settings > Keyboard > Input Method Set Up]

[image: List of Languages]

(Sorry for the French screenshots :) ).

Comment: That has worked perfectly for me. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is:

Go to "System Preferences" -> "Language  & Region".

Under "Preferred languages" add "English (US)" and remove "English".

This changed the spell checking from British English to American English.

Comment: Regardless of what you have set in Preferred Languages, spellcheck in Apple apps can be set to either US or UK English, or French, or Spanish or whatever via System Preferences > Keyboard > Text > Spelling (or in the app via Edit > Spelling and Grammar > Show Spelling and Grammar

Answer (score 0):

These answers were great for the most part but have slowly aged out of date after ten years. I'm currently on Mojave 10.14.6 here. The global option remains in the Text section of the Keyboard preference pane but that section has mostly been taken over by text expansion. Spelling has moved so here's a couple of screenshots to pilot you in:

[image: Keyboard Text Preference Pane Mojave 10.14.6]

[image: Set spelling language expanded]

One can set multiple languages. Here's the ones I have set:

[image: Set multiple languages via checkbox Mojave 10.14.6]

You can also change the language for spelling while in an application.

[image: setting the spelling language from within in an application]