# How to change the spell-check to British -ize in Mac?

Tags: keyboard, internationalization, language, dictionary

It is possible to change the spelling dictionary to either British (-ise) or American (-ize) as shown in the solution to [this post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/57883/how-can-i-change-the-language-for-automatic-spelling-correction).

However, I would like to use British spelling with -ize variant (recalled as en_GB-ize in some dictionaries). Is there a way to set this language in Mac?

Answer (score 1):

Try setting your spellcheck language to Canadian English.

An alternative would be to see if you can find a 3rd party dictionary that does what you want from sources like [this](http://m10lmac.blogspot.com/search?q=dictionaries).